# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess' when creating virtual enviroment

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

i'm trying to set a virtual enviroment with:

> $ python3 -m venv cv2

But when trying it, i'm getting this exception:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/venv/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in  apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/venv/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'
```

I've trying reinstalling subprocess32, but i haven't solved anything. I'm using Python 3.6.3 Anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
Any suggestions?